# No commit for Ignite CacheStoreAdapter

Tags: java, persistence, ignite

Mistake with CacheStoreAdapter. When its method sessionEnd is called a connection of CacheStoreSessionResource is always is closed. There are no any exceptions. But indeed transaction is not commited and no any changes in a database. My code is very simple. All is done according to the original Ignite examples.

**Client**

```
IgniteCache<String, String> typeCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("typeCache");
try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC,
        TransactionIsolation.REPEATABLE_READ)) {
    typeCache.put("code", "name");
    tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("ERROR. Put Type: " + type, e);
}
```

**Server:**

```
public class CacheJdbcTypeStore extends CacheStoreAdapter<String, String> {

    @CacheStoreSessionResource
    private CacheStoreSession ses;

    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends String, ? extends String> entry) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String val = entry.getValue();

        try (Connection conn = connection(ses)) {
            try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "insert into t_type (code, name) values (?, ?)")) {
                st.setString(1, key);
                st.setString(2, val);
                st.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CacheWriterException("Failed to write Type " + val, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionEnd(boolean commit) {
        try (Connection conn = ses.attachment()) {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed() && ses.isWithinTransaction()) {
                if (commit)
                    conn.commit();
                else
                    conn.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CacheWriterException("Failed to end store session of Type cache", e);
        }
    }

    private Connection connection(CacheStoreSession ses) throws Exception {
        if (ses.isWithinTransaction()) {
            Connection conn = ses.attachment();
    /************************************/
    /* Here conn always is closed. WHY???? */
    /* As result transaction is never commited !!!! */
    /************************************/
            if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
                conn = openConnection(false);
                ses.attach(conn);
            }
            return conn;
        }
        else {
            return openConnection(true);
        }
    }

    // Opens JDBC connection.
    private Connection openConnection(boolean autocommit) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        conn.setAutoCommit(autocommit);
        return conn;
    }

    @Override
    public String load(final String key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object key) {
    }

}
```

**Configuration**

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="typeCache" />
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
            <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL" />
            <property name="backups" value="1" />
            <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder"
                    factory-method="factoryOf">
                    <constructor-arg
                    value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcTypeStore" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
            <property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use try-with-resource for connection, so each time, when you leave this block, a connection will be closed.

```
try (Connection conn = ses.attachment()) {}
```

I think you checked this implementation:https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-cachestore-example
but, as you can see, it mentioned that it's not a transactional.
 Please check [this](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcBlobStore.java) cache store implementation as an example of transactional cache store

Also, to see non null value in conn variable, try to add more than one insert inside transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I’ll check this option. Just Ignite documentation contains this snippet for JDBC transactional way:

      // This mehtod is called whenever "put(...)" methods are called on IgniteCache.
      @Override public void write(Cache.Entry<Long, Person> entry) {
        try (Connection conn = connection()) {
      ………
        }        
        catch (SQLException e) {
          throw new CacheWriterException("Failed to write [key=" + key + ", val=" + val + ']', e);
        }
      }

Comment: updated answer, as I understand, it's an issue in doc , that should be fixed

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's issue in the Ignite doc. If to open connection inside regular 'try' statement the code put data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

So the Ignite Documentation contains wrong example of jdbc-transactional CacheStoreAdapter implementation.
In the 'server' code above I've made minor changes which remove mistake.

```
try {
    Connection conn = connection(ses);
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(
                "insert into t_type (code, name) values (?, ?)");
            st.setString(1, key);
            st.setString(2, val);
            st.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CacheWriterException("Failed to write Type " + val, e);
    }
```